# golang - decode dynamic 'flat' http-json response

Tags: json, parsing, go, orientdb

I am trying to parse a dynamic http-json response in a classic go-struct. I am working with orient-db and the problem is the follow:

- there are ever static element for each object
- each object has custom attributes

For example, a pseudo-struct-response could be:

```
type orientdb_reply struct {
  # the "statics" elements that we always have
  element_type string   `json:"@type"`
  rid          string   `json:"@rid"`
  version      int      `json:"@version"`
  class        string   `json:"@class"`

  # then we have custom attributes for each object

  # for example, object 'server' can have
  hostname     string   `json:"hostname"`
  ip           string   `json:"ip"`

  # object 'display' can have
  model         string  `json:"model"`
  serial_number string  `json:"serial_number"`
  resolution    string  `json:"resolution"`

  # and so on
}
```

The difficulty in this case is that the response is "flat", if it contains sub-element the resolution is trivial and could be adding simply other structs as child.

But in this case I would like avoid to build a mega-huge struct that contains each possible attribute and I would like to keep the structure separate for object-type without repeating the constants elements in each object-struct.

Is this possible?

---

A possible solution, that now I see could be:

```
type constant_fields struct {
  # the "constants" elements that we ever have
  element_type string   `json:"@type"`
  rid          string   `json:"@rid"`
  version      int      `json:"@version"`
  class        string   `json:"@class"`
}

type server_fields struct {
  constants     constant_fields
  # for example, object 'server' can have
  hostname     string   `json:"hostname"`
  ip           string   `json:"ip"`
}

type display_fields struct {
  constants     constant_fields
  # object 'display' can have
  model         string  `json:"model"`
  serial_number string  `json:"serial_number"`
  resolution    string  `json:"resolution"`
}
```

But this means that I should parse twice each request (one for constants stuff and another for the attributes stuff). And I don't know if the parser likes a "strange" struct (`constant_fields`) not really present in the json.

---

Real example:

```
{
   "result" : [
      {
         "name" : "cen110t",
         "guest_state" : "running",
         "@type" : "d",
         "guest_mac_addr" : "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX",
         "@version" : 1,
         "hostname" : "",
         "vm_uid" : "vm-29994",
         "guest_ip" : "10.200.1.92",
         "vm_type" : "VirtualMachine",
         "@rid" : "#13:103",
         "guest_family" : "linuxGuest",
         "storage_type" : "",
         "guest_fullname" : "CentOS 4/5/6/7 (64-bit)",
         "@class" : "VM"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have any information that allows you to determine if the json that you just received is a "display", a "server" or whatever ?

Comment: Could you add some XML samples?

Comment: @SebastienC. usually, I already know what kind of object should receive for response. But can even be something more generic like: ```SELECT FROM V``` (get all nodes of each kind).

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur added response -> we work with JSON only response (no XML)

Answer (score 1):

`I would like avoid to build a mega-huge struct that contains each possible attribute`

use json.RawMessage for a attribute type in you struct definition, then this attribute will be kept in raw and not parsed.

`I would like to keep the structure separate for object-type without repeating the statics element in each object-struct`

of cause you can nest struct in struct, just like json object in json object. put the common(statics) attributes in one json object and nest it is a good way.

`to the question update`

yes it will work. json parser will handle nested struct for you, not need to parse twice. but your json string need match the Go's struct structure. like json

```
{
    "k1":"v1",
    "k2":{
        "k21":"v21"
    }
}
```

will match go struct:

```
type nest_struct struct{
    K21 string `k21`
}

type top struct{
    K1 string `k1`,
    K2 nest_struct `k2`
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. What you suggest about the second statement, is something like my updated possible solution? I will take a look now for the ```RawMessage``` function

Comment: yep I see, the problem is that the incoming-json is "flat" (see updated question -> real example) and as I said this mean that I should parse twice each incoming response. Unfortunately I don't think that the ```json.RawMessage``` is useful in this case, because the number of arguments can varying.

Comment: not real, can you mark the 'static' attributes in your 'real json string'?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change how the incoming json looks like. It is done by orientdb

Comment: i see. for your situation, i think parse json to map[string]interface{} is better. free to access attributes by 'string' key. map json to struct not necessary if you have variant structures.

Comment: +1 yes, your proposal to use ```map[string]interface{}``` can do the trick. But even here I should cast again all the attributes and I will loose the "structs-structure" advantages

Comment: maybe implement a unmarshaller which can convert `map[string]interface{}` to your custom `struct`, by reflect. or code generation with help of template, to generate all "static attributes" sources for every struct.